# Yahoo IMAP with mutt, login failure

Tags: email, mutt, yahoo-mail

```
set imap_user = "imap://(user)@imap.mail.yahoo.com:993/"
set imap_pass = "(password)"
set ssl_starttls=yes
set ssl_force_tls = yes
#set smtp_url = "smtp://(user)@smtp.mail.yahoo.com:587/"
#set smtp_pass = "(password")
set from = "(user)"
set realname = ""
set folder = "imaps://export.imap.mail.yahoo.com:993"
set spoolfile = "+INBOX"

set header_cache=~/.mutt/cache/headers
set message_cachedir=~/.mutt/cache/bodies
set certificate_file=~/.mutt/certificates
```

I'm not sure what else is going wrong as it just gives me a "login failed" error.

Answer (score 3):

You should [generate an app password](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/generate-password-sln15241.html) and use that as your password, instead of your main account's password.

More info:
https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN28681.html